# Falla de validación

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de validar un prompt. Cuando inserto un dato erróneo para probarlo al principio funciona pero luego le quiero poner un dato válido y no lo toma, sigue entrando al ciclo. Si le inserto un dato válido la primera vez funciona. Tampoco me deja validar el número 0 cuando debería tomarlo.
No logro ver el error. 
Les dejo el código:

```js
(function obtenerMinutos() {
     let min = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese minutos de tardanza'));

     while (isNaN(min) || min == '' || min < 0) {
          obtenerMinutos();
     }

     return min;
})();

let minutos = obtenerMinutos();
```

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los valores permitidos y cuáles los rechazados?

Comment: Permitidos: números mayores que 0. Rechazados: letras e input vacío

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo este ejemplo:

```
let contador = false

do{
  let ingreso = prompt("Teclea un valor")
  if(isNaN(ingreso) || ingreso === "" || ingreso < 0) {
    console.log("Erróneo")
  }else{
    console.log("Correcto")
    contador = true
  }
}while(contador === false)
```

**Lo que hice fue lo siguiente**

- Declaro una bandera que es falsa y **asi seguirá en tanto el valor ingresado no sea un número mayor a 0**
- El bloque de código interno se va a mantener en ejecución, mientras la variable `contador` sea igual a `false`
- Con un condicional simple, verificamos si el valor ingresado no es un número o el valor es un espacio vacío o un número menor a 0
- Cuando el valor ingresado cumple o satisface la condición de no encajar en alguna de las 3 condiciones dadas, entonces convertimos la variable `contador` a `true` lo cual generará que el ciclo se detenga

Answer (score 0):

Mmmmm bueno intentaré explicar el error y como logré corregirlo:

Tienes un `while` que se encuentra iterando infinitas veces cuando un valor ingresado es inválido:

```
while (isNaN(min) || min == '' || min < 0) {
     obtenerMinutos();
}
```

Algo que hace que después de que entra un valor inválido en este caso `0` se inicia dicha iteración y cuando quieres ingresar un valor valido éste no te obedece ya que el `while` anterior se sigue ejecutando. **(OJO esto es desde mi punto de vista de como veo que ocurre el error)** posiblemente me equivoque y estoy seguro que si me equivoco alguien me corregirá en los comentarios cosa que agradezco.

Ahora bien para que te funcione podrias simplemente agregar un `return` dentro del while para que la iteración se rompa y así inicie nuevamente de la siguiente forma:

```
(function obtenerMinutos() {
     let min = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese minutos de tardanza'));

     while (isNaN(min) || min == '' || min < 0) {
          return obtenerMinutos();
     }

     return min;
})();

let minutos = obtenerMinutos();
```

Probé el código y me funciona, espero que sea el resultado que esperas ;) Saludos.